# Threading in python with nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with Threading in python. Actually I want run some code on my raspberry pi zero. I have to use threading to getting value of sensors in diffrent time and diffrent refresh rate. Threads have to work in loop while to getting values of sensors in n - times.

```
def main():
    db=connect_database('sensors.db')
    sensors,refresh_rate_sensor = read_sensor_configuration()
```

`sensors` is nested dict looks like this:

```
{'test': {'name': 'SENSOROWY TEST'}, 'dht': {'name': 'Sensor temperature and humidity outside2_22', 'dht_type': '22', 'pin': '2', 'quantity': 'temperature', 'quantity1': 'humidity'}}
```

`refresh_rate_sensor` is dict looks like this:

```
{'test': '2', 'dht': '4'}
```

```
properties_list = [] 

  i=0
  thread_list =[]
  for sensor,value in sensors.items():           #example loop values : sensor=test 
    for properties in value:                     #in this loop I creating list to adding 
                                                 # "properties" example value : name
      properties_list.append(value[properties])

    thread = threading.Thread(target=read_sensor_value, args=[sensor,refresh_rate_sensor[sensor],properties_list,db])
    thread_list.append(thread)
    thread_list[i].start()
    i+=1
    # t = threading.Thread(target=read_sensor_value, args=[sensor,refresh_rate_sensor[sensor],properties_list,db])
    # t.start()
    properties_list.clear()                           #deleting list to get new properties of diffrent sensor
  for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
```

Thread run function that will be getting information about sensor and wait `time.sleep(int(refresh_rate))` and getting again values in infinity loop. I'd like to add this function insert new variables to database too.

```
read_sensor_value(sensor,refresh_rate,properties_list,db):
```

I have a problem with properties_list because when it first run it getting arguments from second iteration loop. When I run without using threads this working nice but not in the same time.
I'd like to add i+=1 is test variable because I try many of options.
How to deal with kind of problem ?
Maybe you have better option to implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are re-using `properties_list` object for all the threads so every thread see the same object which is changing.

Your code should be something like that (did not tested):

```
thread_list =[]
for sensor, value in sensors.items():           #example loop values : sensor=test 
    properties_list = value.values()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=read_sensor_value, 
                 args=[sensor,refresh_rate_sensor[sensor], properties_list, db])
    thread_list.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
```